# How to integrate Chart.js in Django?

Tags: python, django, charts

So first of all, I am a bloody beginner at Django and Chart.js.
What I want to do: I want to display a pie chart. I know that with the syntax {{content}} a .html template can get dynamic data but it doesn't work for my piechart template.

What I have: I have my pie chart ready as a .html template for my app. It already works perfectly fine when I directly code the data into the template.

my view:

```
    def index(request):

    return render(
        request, 
        "mep/chart.html",
        {
            labels: ['F', 'M'],
            data: [52, 82],
            colors: ["#FF4136", "#0074D9"]
            }

        )
```

my template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    <title>Geschlechtsverteilung Patientendaten </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',// bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea

            data: {
                labels: {{labels}},
                datasets: [{
                    data: {{data}},
                    backgroundColor: {{colors}}
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Geschlechtsverteilung Patientendaten',
                },
                legend: {
                    disblay: true,
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000'
                    }
                }

            }


        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see I am TRYING to pass the data for the template in my views.py but it doesn't work. 
When I specified the data directly in the chart.html it worked

Any solutions???

Comment: of course it has to ne 'labels', 'data' and 'colors' in my views.py

Comment: You should make the request for data via AJAX rather than trying to generate the JS list via view and template.

Comment: What are the values of those variables when you view the source of the rendered template, Also, "doesn't work" isn't a good description of the output

Comment: In your `views.py`, is it `data: [52, 82]` or `'data':[52,82]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code. First, you need to correct your **views.py**.

You need to use `strings` as `keys` in your `context dictionary`, so you need to change it to:

```
def index(request):

    return render(
        request, 
        "base/chart.html",
        {
            'labels': ['F', 'M'],
            'data': [52, 82],
            'colors': ["#FF4136", "#0074D9"]
            }

        )
```

And then you need to specify inside the `django template`, that these variables are `safe` to render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    <title>Geschlechtsverteilung Patientendaten </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',// bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea

            data: {
                labels: {{labels|safe}},
                datasets: [{
                    data: {{data|safe}},
                    backgroundColor: {{colors|safe}}
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Geschlechtsverteilung Patientendaten',
                },
                legend: {
                    disblay: true,
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000'
                    }
                }

            }


        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to output into the html by iterating through the items.  So, for example, change `labels: {{labels}},` to

```
labels: [{% for label in labels %}{{ label }}{% endfor %}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the code, that could be an issue. Substitute `disblay` with the correct `display` in options -> title -> display in Chart initialization. Could you please provide your javascript console output if this fix doesn't work?