# How to get value of defaultdic in JS (Django framework)?

Tags: django, chart.js

I want to use chartjs to display a chart on the page (Django framework).

views.py

```
chart_data = defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'3': 2, '2': 2, '8': 2, '5': 2, '7': 1})
context["chart_data"] = chart_data
```

home.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_chart = "{{ chart_data }}";
</script>
```

my_chart.js

```
  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: Object.values(my_chart),
    }]
  };
```

But it didn't work. When I used `console.log(Object.values(my_chart))` to check, I found that what `Object.values(my_chart)` returns was ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'u', 'l', 't', 'd', 'i', 'c', 't', '(', '&', 'l', 't', ';', 'c', 'l', 'a', 's', 's', ' ', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', 'i', 'n', 't', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', '&', 'g', 't', ';', ',', ' ', '{', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', '3', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', ':', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', '2', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', ':', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', '8', '&', '#', 'x', '2', '7', ';', ':', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '&', '#', …], it just disassembled each letter and symbol of the dictionary.

Do you know how can I get the value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate Chart.js in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832576/how-to-integrate-chart-js-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass javascript by rendering the object in the template. That will render it like the `str(…)` of the object. It is possible that for some objects, that will produce text that is a valid JavaScript expression, but often, as is here the case, it will not.

You can make use of the [**`|json_script:…`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) to render data as a JSON object, and then load this in a JavaScript script, so:

```
{{ chart_data|json_script:"my_chart" }}

<script type="text/javascript">
var my_chart = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('my_chart').textContent)
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: Object.values(my_chart),
    }]
  };
</script>
```